# data send by JSON are always null

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, asp.net-mvc

#### First problem

I work with code for another coder.

I must check correctly cron expression and I can change many line code in program. I take argument from form and trying send this data to controller MVC

```
var outl = document.getElementById('Frequency').value;
var tmp = checkValid(outl);
```

and

```
function checkValid(checkExpression)
{
    var tmp = JSON.stringify(checkExpression);
    $.ajax({
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: String,
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/Service/isValid',
        data: tmp,
        success: function (isvalid)
        {
            return isvalid;
        }
    });
    console.log(tmp);
}
```

Controller in MVC looks like:

```
public JsonResult isValid(string dataFromJson)
{
    Options options = new Options()
    {
        ThrowExceptionOnParseError = true,
        Use24HourTimeFormat = true,
    };

    try
    {
        ExpressionDescriptor ceh = new ExpressionDescriptor(dataFromJson, options);
        string description = ceh.GetDescription(DescriptionTypeEnum.FULL);
        return Json(true);
    }
    catch (FormatException)
    {
         return Json(false);
    }
 }
```

The parameters `dataFromJson` are llways null. Why? Really, I don't see where I went wrong.

#### Second part

In controller I return JSON - its good idea? How to get response from this controller in Ajax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `ajax` data as follows.

```
function checkValid(checkExpression)
{
var tmp = JSON.stringify({dataFromJson : checkExpression});
$.ajax({
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: "json",
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/Service/isValid',
    data: tmp,
    success: function (isvalid)
    {
        return isvalid;
    }
    });
   console.log(tmp);
}
```

In the above, i changed `var tmp = JSON.stringify({dataFromJson : checkExpression});` this, now it can be bound at the server side.  And also change the `dataType` as `json` if you are expecting a json from server response.

Regarding the second part, its based on your requirement, you can either use `Content` or `Json` as per your need.

Answer (score 0):

Change the paramter type of the Controller action method to JObject (Newtonsoft.Json.Linq)or dynamic
public JsonResult isValid(JObject dataFromJson)

or JsonResult isValid(dynamic dataFromJson)